# Sort list of lists with respect to specific columns

Tags: python, list, sorting, conditional-statements

Lets say I have 3 vitamins with levels of C-Vitamin and D-Vitamin

```
ls = [[100,50],[100,49],[100,64]]
```

Now by coincidence these vitamins all have the same amount of C-vitamin. Therefore I want to sort with regard to a second condition (D-Vitamin). How would I achieve that? I have done a little research and found this as an example:

```
mylist = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter('name', 'age'))
```

However I don't understand how or why it works. I have achieved sorting the list with regard to one condition using a class with helpmethods and this line:

```
ls.sort(key=Vitamin.get_cVitamin, reverse=True)
```

I would preferably want to build onto that..

Comment: Python's sort is lexicographic, so for your example, just `ls.sort()` will work fine.

Comment: Note to answerers: diaco doesn't say they want to sort **only** with respect to the second item, and in fact says "these vitamins all have the same amount of C-vitamin. Therefore ...".

Comment: lol cheers. I may have been a little bit unclear with what the actual question was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard sort will by default take into account the other columns of the contained lists.

So, only use the plain sort function without any key.

```
ls = [[100,50],[100,49],[100,64]]
ls.sort()
# ls is sorted w.r.t. all "columns": [[100, 49], [100, 50], [100, 64]]
```

Also have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) [emphasis mine]:

> Sequence types also support comparisons. **In particular, tuples and lists are compared lexicographically by comparing corresponding elements.** This means that to compare equal, every element must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and have the same length. (For full details see [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) in the language reference.)

If you however need to select specific columns to define the sort order, I recommend using  [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for the `key` function.

Answer (score 6):

If one value of the sublist is same in all sublists of the list, `sorted()` method by default sorts by other value , the one that is different. You don't need to use `lambda`.

Demo:

```
>>> ls = [[100,50],[100,49],[100,64]]
>>> sorted(ls)
[[100, 49], [100, 50], [100, 64]]
>>> ls = [[50,100],[49,100],[64,100]]
>>> sorted(ls)
[[49, 100], [50, 100], [64, 100]]
```

Sort by multiple keys:

```
>>> ls=[["kfajksa",100,20,40],["jsaof",120,32,94],["skajd",120,28,94],["jhsgd",120,32,84]]
>>> sorted(ls, key=lambda x:(x[2],x[3]))
[['kfajksa', 100, 20, 40], ['skajd', 120, 28, 94], ['jhsgd', 120, 32, 84], ['jsaof', 120, 32, 94]]
```

Here the list is first sorted on 2nd index i.e., **1st key** and where the values on index 2nd are equal, index 3rd i.e., **2nd key** is used to sort at those situations.

Comment: alright! that looks good. I forgot to mention one thing though. What if I have more items in every sublist and want to sort by lets say two.

demo

ls=[["kfajksa",100,20,40],["jsaof",120,32,94]....]

Lets say I want to sort by item [2] and [3]

Comment: Then you have to use `lambda` with multiple keys. I've posted an example in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls.sort(key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
print(ls)

[[100, 64], [100, 50], [100, 49]]
```

To sort by the first element  breaking ties by the second element you would use the following :

```
ls.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]),reverse=True)
```

Whatever elements you want to sort by you would use in the lambda i.e 2nd,3rd elements would be `(x[1],x[2])`.

If you are only dealing with numbers you can just sort:

```
ls = [[100,50],[100,49],[100,64]]
ls.sort(reverse=True)
```